# SQLExceptionHelper : Input parameter not set, Index : 0

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, sybase, spring-data-rest, sap-iq

I am using spring-data-rest & hibernate to expose a table "File(Id, Name)" from a SAP IQ(Sybase IQ) database. The below error occurs when I do a "GET" on the "File" table using "curl http://localhost:8080/files/1".

```
2022-07-20 20:01:03 WARN  [http-nio-8081-exec-1] o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: JZ0SA
2022-07-20 20:01:03 ERROR [http-nio-8081-exec-1] o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - JZ0SA: Prepared Statement: Input parameter not set, index: 0.
2022-07-20 20:01:03 INFO  [http-nio-8081-exec-1] o.h.e.i.DefaultLoadEventListener - HHH000327: Error performing load command
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:67)
```

I have the same table in "Sybase 16" but it is working perfectly with the same code base.

Anyone faced similar issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30632084/how-do-i-execute-preparedstatementselect-object-id-in-sybase-iq will this help?

Comment: Thanks @AshishPatil, I checked it as well, but didn't work for me.